# How to render the iphone device screens on mac OS or in windows

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

We have an iphone device in our company and for the remote demo purpose I have to show some of the device specific features like voice call, accelerometer etc. (which is not possible on a iphone simulator), from a mac / windows system. Is there any way to render the device screens on mac /windows machine?

Advance Thanks,
Sathish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this but there is a private API MPTVOutWindow which can be used. For details on how look at this blog post http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/3

As this is a private API, it needs to be built into your app and it will never pass the app store submission process whilst it is in the app.

An easier way would be to set up a web cam overhead above the phone.

Comment: Thanks Bruce for your options but I am still searching for some live rendering from device to mac/windows system.

Comment: No worries ... just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot by pressing both hardware buttons simultaneously (power at the top and home at the bottom). You can then mail the images or sync to get them onto the computer. If you need to show the application in action, not just static screens, you could separate the assets and animate in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does this with iPhones at their keynote speeches and at WWDC all the time. However, it seems that they have "special" iPhones; some presenters use the camera-over-the-iPhone approach and some have direct iPhone-to-video connections. Regardless, this is not currently possible on an iPhone that you haven't jailbroken. Your best bet is to simulate it.